How to append time-series data with PyArrow Datasets?
Problem
I'm looking to store time-series data that's being aggregated live to Parquet Datasets via PyArrow. I receive live batched data, for example, video view count each hour for the last 24 hours. The latest hour is a running sum, so if I poll multiple times during that hour, it'll give me a different value each time.
This means that the latest timestamp of any batch is "incomplete" as it updates. I need to wait for the next aggregation period (hour) before the previous hour's data is finalized.
What I'm Doing
My current method is to create a new parquet file for each new batch of data I receive and run a separate job periodically to consolidate all the parquet files.  With this approach, there are be duplicate entries due to "incomplete" aggregations. Of these, I need to keep the latest and delete the rest. Currently I take the last record where there are duplicate timestamps. This assumes Pyarrow Datasets are ordered by insert (not sure if it holds).
My goal is to reduce the cost of deduplicating data. Currently I need to load the entire dataset into memory in order to deduplicate it.
Alternatives I'm Considering
I'm looking for ways of ensuring Pyarrow Dataset is sorted when I load it. This way I'll just overwrite the last record, corresponding to the incomplete entry on each batch insert. No separate deduplication job required.
I'm not sure if the Pyarrow dataset will stay sorted once I load it, considering I'm partitioning by other columns (like country), and some datasets aren't even partitioned by date. I've also heard of SortingColumn, which has to do with RowGroup but I'm not too familiar with. Do they work with PyArrow Dataset API?
I realize Avro may be a better for what I'm doing, but long term I should be using Parquet for the sizes I'm working with. If there are combined solutions that use both Parquet and Avro, I'd be interested as well.

Maybe we would help better if we could see some code.
Beside that, why not using filters on dates and date partitionning per hour ? That way you can just write your new partition corresponding to the last hour (you run it at 07:01pm for the batch >= 6pm and <7pm), and you don't have to load all previous data into memory. I don't know how do you read your data but you could also use parquet predicate pushdown to push dates filters down the reader and avoid reading unwanted rows at read step

@FairPluto, The code is rather ugly and need to be sanitized before it can be shown and for it to make sense. What you suggest is really helpful, and I ended up doing something similar. For partitioning on the hourly, I often hear it's bad practice to more than a few thousand partitions. Are you thinking of performing a second roll-up job to then partition it to larger timeframes (eg monthly)?
